# How can i move the first element in an array and move it to the last in c programming?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

If I have an array, let's say [1,2,3,4,5,6], how can I make it to be [2,3,4,5,6,1]? Which loop should I use for this? I tried using a for loop, however since I am fairly new to C programming I was unable to produce the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int array_size = 6;

// array is now { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }

int array = array[0];                        // #1

for(int i = 1; i < array_size; i++) {        // #2
   array[i - 1] = array[i];
}

array[array_size - 1] = tmp;                 // #3

// array is now { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 }
```

It works like this:

1. Take the first value and store it in a special variable, `tmp`.
2. Take each of the remainding values and move one step to the front of the array.
3. Take the value stored in `tmp` and move it to the back of the array.

Comment: @Sifu I don't see the problem with my answer? I don't think the question directly indicates that this is necessarily any type of homework, and thus I try to answer it as clearly as I can.

Comment: I gave you thumbs-up because it works, I don't know why you got a thumbs-down either.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. I misread the problem the first time

```
int len = 5;
char *pOriginal = {0,1,2,3,4}
char ch0 = pOrigina[0];
memmove(pOriginal, &pOrigina[1], len-2) // Thanks guys!
pOriginal[len-1] = ch0;
```

Comment: This won't work. The question is very clearly `"how do I rotate the array by moving the first element to the end?"` Your answer just swaps the first and last elements, which is not the same.

Comment: @Jashaszun Exactly what I was writing.

Comment: Yes, I was to quick to start coding -- Gotta beat the competition!

Comment: Passing overlapping memory regions to `memcpy` results in undefined behavior. ([hint](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memmove.html) on how to fix this).

Comment: I've read it's undefined, but I've only ever see it work. Why? Because it must do the read first. There's no other way.

Comment: @SingleStepper: An implementation of `memcpy` might be: `void memcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t len) { for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) dst[i] = src[i]; }`. This would lead to weird side effects  if the memory regions overlap.

Comment: In this case, we moving bytes right to left, so it's like a shift left that does not over-write itself.  But I strongly agree that if the dest was > source, then the results are undefined in an overlap.

Comment: @SingleStepper A valid implementation can also move bytes in the reverse order, in which case the code in question would not work. You can't know how `memcpy` is implemented, thus it is undefined behavior if they overlap in any way.

Comment: I know for certain in this instance that I am moving code from higher in memory &pOriginal[1] to lower memory &pOriginal[0] -- Therefore, it will read what is higher, and put that lower.  It cannot put what it has not read, so it will read the hi memory, then copy to low. It is impossible to do anything else.  Or else I'm nuts.

Comment: @SingleStepper: It doesn't matter that it hasn't failed for you yet. The language standard says it's undefined behavior so relying on it is a bad practice. If the areas overlap just use `memmove()`.

Comment: @SingleStepper To quote the manpage for [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html): "The `memcpy()` function copies `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`.  The memory areas must not overlap. Use `memmove()` if the memory areas do overlap."

Comment: OK! OK! I'll change my answer!

Comment: This will work, but only for byte arrays. Can you edit it to make it work with any size elements? (It's a small but useful change.)